# Module not found in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I have create new react app using following command.

```
create-react-app app-name --scripts-version custom-react-scripts-version
```

Inside src folder of that app i have created 2 new folders say **Grid** and **Title** and created files Grid.js and Title.js in respected folder.

**Grid.js**

```
import React from 'React';

export default class Grid extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Grid</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Title.js**

```
import React from 'React';

const Title = () =>  {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Title;
```

Now, i try to import both into **App.js** file it won't.

```
import Title from './Title/Title';
import Grid from './Grid/Grid';
```

It shows following error.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/Grid/Grid.js
>   Module not found: `D:\ReactAppCSS\node_modules\React\index.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `react`.

Same for Title.js.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look what the error says - `\React\index.js` doesn't match the corresponding path on disk `react`

Comment: Yeah, Path is perfect i checked many times

Comment: Oh it was a comment regarding the capitalization of `React` in the path. Also when you see `node_modules` being looked into, you know that the import statement doesn't start with `./`, `../`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
```

react is the package name!